# How do i write a conditional for the possibility of an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a users list that im mapping over in a little side bar. Theres a possiblity that there can be no users. So I would like the side bar to say none if theres no users. I tried the below method but it seems like its still registering the user, even if its 0. I've tried `(user === null)` and `(user.length < 1)` but just cant seem to get it.

```
{usersList.map((user) => {
  if (!user) {
    return <h5>none</h5>;
  } else {
    return (
      <h5
        key={user}
      >
        <Link
          to={`/user/${user}`}
          style={{ textDecoration: "none"}}
        >
          {user}
        </Link>
      </h5>
    );
  }
})}
```

Comment: How is `usersList` defined and what is its value? What is the value of `user`?

Comment: You need to check the length of `userList` instead of `user` before you invoke your map operation.

Comment: @showdev I literally filtered the original data to just an array of users. So when theres no users its just ```[]``` but if there are users ```["Bob", "Kim"]```

Comment: If the array is empty, I wouldn't expect `map` to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the array length is greater than 0: if so, display the list, otherwise display "none"

You can do this with a simple ternary operator:

```js
condition ? truthy : falsey
```

```
{usersList.length > 0 ? (
  usersList.map((user) => (
    <h5 key={user}>
      <Link to={`/user/${user}`} style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
        {user}
      </Link>
    </h5>
  ))
) : (
  <h5>none</h5>
)}
```

Comment: Ahhh didn't know you can ternary a map func. Thanks for the lesson

Comment: You can put just about anything inside a ternary conditional

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
{
 userList?.length > 0 ?  <h5
    key={user}
  >
    <Link
      to={`/user/${user}`}
      style={{ textDecoration: "none"}}
    >
      {user}
    </Link>
  </h5> :
 <h5>No Users</h5>
}
```

or can use &&

```
{(!userList || userList?.length === 0) &&  <h5>No Users</h5>}
{userList?.length > 0 && <h5
    key={user}
  >
    <Link
      to={`/user/${user}`}
      style={{ textDecoration: "none"}}
    >
      {user}
    </Link>
  </h5>}
```